# Memory leaks in python wrapper for C++ algorithm

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks

I'm writing a python-wrapper for C++ algorithm.

- The input of wrapper is a single string or list of ones,
- the output is a single number or list.

The main function of this wrapper is below:

```
PyObject* count_rep_list(PyObject *mod, PyObject *args){
    PyObject *inputList = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0);
    PyObject *outputList = PyList_New(0);
    char* str;
    if(PyList_Check(inputList)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < PyList_Size(inputList); ++i) {
            PyObject *list_item = PyList_GetItem(inputList, i);
            if (!PyArg_Parse(list_item, "s", &str)) {
                Py_XDECREF(list_item);
                Py_XDECREF(inputList);
                Py_XDECREF(outputList);
                return NULL;
            }
            Py_DECREF(list_item);
            PyList_Append(outputList, PyLong_FromSize_t(repeating_count::count(string(str))));
        }
    }
    else if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str)){
        Py_XDECREF(inputList);
        Py_XDECREF(outputList);
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        PyList_Append(outputList, PyLong_FromSize_t(repeating_count::count(string(str))));
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

The realization of the `repeating_count::count()` doesn't matter.

Are there **memory leaks** in this code? How can I fix them?

I know, that `PyArg_Parse()` and `PyArg_ParseTuple()` allocate memory for `str` dynamically. But how can I free this memory if parsing failed? I don't know **how** this memory was allocated, therefore I can't free it.  So,

- `free(str)`,
- `delete(str)`,
- `delete str`,
- `delete[] str`

aren't working.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you see those `Py_XDECREF`s? There's reference counting for the objects.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, yes, but `Py_XDECREF` and `Py_DECREF` works only for `PyObject`s. What should I do If I want to free memoty after `char*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> You must not provide storage for the string itself; a pointer to an
>   existing string is stored into the character pointer variable whose
>   address you pass.

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ext/parseTuple.html

You're getting a pointer to the python managed string, you aren't responsible for freeing the memory.